Incorrect passphrase after cancelled transaction
Bitcoin Core after sending the transaction showed the incorrect balance and the transaction was cancelled. During that incorrect balance there was a sending operation after which the bitcoin core started giving a message about incorrect passphrase, but passphrase is correct, since the account has been used for many transactions for more than a year, and there was no issue with the passphrase before. How can I fix this problem? I need to send BTC to another account.


How can I fix this problem

I would

Check that I don't have multiple wallets
Check that I am loading the right wallet.

Then

Make a safe copy of the problematic wallet.dat
Temporarily suspend my regular backup processes.
Make a careful inventory of both onsite and off-site backups of wallet.dat or which contain it.
Select the backup closest to the point in time the problem first appeared
Restore and test that backup
Repeat for progressively older backups until one succeeds.
If none succeeded and the amount in the wallet was less than a month's income I would write it off and stop.
Spend time thinking up variations of the passphrase, old passphrases, etc.
If the amount involved was several years income I might study the file format in my spare time to see if there was any possibility that malformation could cause the problem. Maybe create modified copies and prune early keys. This would be a pretty hopeless step.

